# SELECT sys_context('userenv','ip_address') FROM dual returns IPV4 but sometimes it returns IPV6

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I am using Oracle 19.10.0.0 database.
for some application server below query returns IPV4 but for some other application server it is returning IPV6.

**SELECT sys_context('userenv','ip_address') FROM dual.**

Could we make sure that this return always IPV4 only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`IP_ADDRESS` [shows the client IP address](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm#g1513460) - if they connected using IPv6, it'll show that address. In that case the server does not know that client's IPv4 address, so there's no way to show it.

If you don't want clients to be able to use IPv6, you would need to disable IPv6 connections. The easiest way would probably be to [disable IPv6 in the Oracle Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/listener.htm#NETRF432), but you could also reconfigure the server OS's network connection to not use IPv6.

Example `listener.ora` entry:

```
listener_name=
 (DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=appservername)(PORT=1521)(IP=V4_ONLY))
```

Comment: After keeping IP=V4_ONLY in listener_name, unable to connect to the database and getting below error.

**ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor**

After removing  IP=V4_ONLY from listener_name, I am able to connect the database.

Any thing else we need to do?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your listener.ora file contents? You could also look in the listener log file for error messages - try `lsnrctl status` to see the current log file location.