# How to obtain the IP address (IPV4) of the Oracle service on PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Maybe it's because of my low version of PLSQL, I can't visually see the service address of Oracle on PLSQL.So I tried to find out how to get oracle service IP address(IPV4) on plsql. And I got the following methods:

1. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS);
2. select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') ipaddr from dual
   But they all have a problem!
   The problem with the first method is that it can only return an address in IPv6 format.
   As for the second method, it can indeed return an address in IPv4 format, but it returns my localhost address!
   So I want to ask you how to get the IPv4 format address of Oracle service on PLSQL.
   Please and thanks a lot.

Comment: Ask your DBA what it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67974630/select-sys-contextuserenv-ip-address-from-dual-returns-ipv4-but-sometimes

Comment: `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS')` only returns the address of the client, not the server/service host.